# How to create a variable which represents [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection] in PnP Power Shell for SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, azure-powershell

When working with SharePoint on-premises, we can define a list of user values as follow :-

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection]$HRCollabs = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection
```

so what is the equivalent way to define such a variable inside PnP Power shell for SharePoint online?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need for that in PnP. You can use a normal powershell list to set multi-user picker field:

```
$HRCollabs= @("one@contoso.com", "two@contoso.com")

Set-PnPListItem -List $YourList -Identity $YourItem -Values @{"YourField" = $HRCollabs }
```